# Filtering and saving subset of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that does the following:

Inserting class values 1,2,3 based on timestamps. This work as inspected and in the first iteration of the first for-loop i get the following class distribution:

```
mapping: {'Seizure': 1, 'Preictal': 2, 'Interictal': 3} 
 value counts: 
3.0    3150000
2.0     450000
1.0      28000
Name: class, dtype:
```

So i have this number of rows for each class.

However in the second forloop i iterate through the same list of timestamps and want to subset the data between the timestamps and include some conditions based on the classes i inserted in first forloop.

This is the result of the same timestamps e.g. first iteration:

```
len sz: 28000
len prei: 450000
len pre int: 29700000
logging
len post int: 1485499
```

How the * does preint and post int (interictal class) get this high of a count? it doesn't at all correspond somewhat to the number interictal in the first?

here my function.

```
def insert_class_col(dataframe, sz_info_list, date_converter, save_filename, save_path, file_sample_rate, file_channel):
    print(f"sz_info_list: {sz_info_list}")
    if "class" not in dataframe.columns:
        dataframe.insert(0, "class", np.nan)
    file_channel.extend(['timestamp', 'class'])
    dataframe = dataframe[file_channel]

    # Insert class attributes to ensure that seizure, preictal, interictal does not overlap.
    for index, container in enumerate(sz_info_list):
        delay = container.delay * 1000
        duration = container.duration * 1000
        sz_start = date_converter(container.time_emu) + delay
        sz_end = sz_start + duration
        print(f"sz_start index = {sz_start}")
        print(f"sz_end: {sz_end}")
        preictal_start = sz_start - (15 * 60 * 1000)
        interictal_start = sz_start - (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        interictal_end = sz_end + (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        dataframe['timestamp'] = pd.to_numeric(dataframe['timestamp'])

        # hvis data er sezure tag seizure
        # hvis data er preictal tag preictal/interictal, men ikke indenfor seizure data.
        dataframe.loc[(dataframe['timestamp'] >= sz_start) & (dataframe['timestamp'] < sz_end), "class"] = class_mapping['Seizure']
        dataframe.loc[(dataframe['class'] != class_mapping['Seizure']) & (dataframe['timestamp'] >= preictal_start) & (dataframe['timestamp'] < sz_start), "class"] = class_mapping['Preictal']
        dataframe.loc[(dataframe['class'] != class_mapping['Seizure']) & (dataframe['class'] != class_mapping['Preictal']) & (dataframe['timestamp'] >= interictal_start) & (dataframe['timestamp'] < interictal_end), "class"] = class_mapping['Interictal']

        print(f"mapping: {class_mapping} \n value counts: \n{dataframe['class'].value_counts()}")
    
    print(f"Begginging current number of class in df {dataframe['class'].value_counts()}")
    # Saving to csv
    for index, container in enumerate(sz_info_list):
        delay = container.delay * 1000
        duration = container.duration * 1000
        sz_start = date_converter(container.time_emu) + delay
        sz_end = sz_start + duration
        print(f"sz_start index = {sz_start}")
        print(f"sz_end: {sz_end}")
        preictal_start = sz_start - (15 * 60 * 1000)
        interictal_start = sz_start - (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        interictal_end = sz_end + (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        dataframe['timestamp'] = pd.to_numeric(dataframe['timestamp'])

        

        #INSERTING SEIZURE CLASS
        sz_df = dataframe[(dataframe['timestamp'] >= sz_start) & (dataframe['timestamp'] < sz_end)].copy()
        print(f"len sz: {len(sz_df)}")
        #df_save_compress(f"Seizure_{index}_{save_filename}", save_path + "/Seizure", sz_df)
        #logging_info_txt(f"Seizure_{index}_{save_filename}", save_path, file_sample_rate, file_channel)

        #INSERTING PREICTAL
        prei_df = dataframe[(dataframe['timestamp'] >= preictal_start) & (dataframe['timestamp'] < sz_start) & (dataframe['class'] != class_mapping["Seizure"])].copy()
        print(f"len prei: {len(prei_df)}")
        #df_save_compress(f"Preictal_{index}_{save_filename}", save_path + "/Preictal", prei_df)
        #logging_info_txt(f"Preictal_{index}_{save_filename}", save_path, file_sample_rate, file_channel)

        #INSERTING INTERICTAL
        pre_int_df = dataframe[(dataframe['timestamp'] >= interictal_start) & (dataframe['timestamp'] < preictal_start) & (dataframe['class'] != class_mapping["Seizure"]) | (dataframe['class'] != class_mapping["Preictal"])].copy()
        print(f"len pre int: {len(pre_int_df)}")
        #df_save_compress(f"PreInt_{index}_{save_filename}", save_path + "/Interictal", pre_int_df)
        logging_info_txt(f"PreInt_{index}_{save_filename}", save_path, file_sample_rate, file_channel)

        post_int_df = dataframe[(dataframe['timestamp'] >= sz_end) & (dataframe['timestamp'] < interictal_end) & (dataframe['class'] != class_mapping["Seizure"]) & (dataframe['class'] != class_mapping["Preictal"])].copy()
        print(f"len post int: {len(post_int_df)}")
        #df_save_compress(f"PostInt_{index}_{save_filename}", save_path + "/Interictal", post_int_df)
        logging_info_txt(f"PostInt_{index}_{save_filename}", save_path, file_sample_rate, file_channel)

        #print(f"after = len df: {len(dataframe)} values class: \n {dataframe['class'].value_counts()}")
        
        # clean up
        del pre_int_df, post_int_df, sz_df, prei_df
        gc.collect()
```

Notice that preint which is interictal is 29700000 while printing the classes i should be lower than 3150000.

Any ideas of this pandas behavior?

Comment: Nevermind... i replaced the "|" with "&" and it worked. Does "|" mean or in pandas ? because i doen't behave like or

Comment: Yes @Niklas, it means OR. If you have to Series objects of the same length containing either True or False values, `|` will return a new Series object where each value will be True if that value from Series is True OR that value from the other Series is True, False if neither are True.

Comment: So the problem was that the or operator what applied to the whole filtering and not only the last part then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@richardec answered the question see comments.